# Gitlab shared runner for c++

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

As I understood Gitlab provides free runners so I don't need to create my own, maintain it. But I couldn't find any information about language support. I'm using c++ and want to know which compiler is used, which version or is c++ supported at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically set everything up as you want in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. For example you can use a docker container that has everything installed that you need. You also can build your application in a build action. Or install packages in the `before_script` section.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/ for examples.

Here is a pseudocode example (I don't use this feature with C++).

```
image: gcc

services:
  - postgres:latest

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: "foo"
  POSTGRES_USER: "foo"
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "bar"

before_script:
  - gcc -v
  - which gcc
  - gcc .

test:
  script:
    - test_runner .
```